# How to get rid off from Pectus Carinatum aka Pigeon chest through diet and workout

Tags: workout-routines, diet, workout, chest, upper-body-workout

I am about 21 years old and I have pigeon chest disease about 3-4 years ago. In start I can not even notice about it but time to time I felt really ashamed to pull off my shirt in front of any people, but issue is that some people also noticed it on the shirt because its clearly noticeable.

About 1-2 month I started workout and diet to getting rid of this disease because I am really in depressed. I do searching on google and YouTube and found that some peoples removed it by gaining proper workout. So I also start workout and do some diet, but till now I can't get too much clear result. Now my pectus is not too much noticeable when I wear shirt but when anyone touches me then it became horrible.

I do a lot of searches online but can not get proper workout for pectus carinatim, everyone talk about pectus excavatum which is totally its opposite. So I am not even guided about its proper workout, which exercise I need to do daily and which diet I need to follow to get rid of this worst.

Recently I am eating oats with 2 boil eggs on breakfast, normal launch and boil normal rice on dinner. My weight is about 54 to 55kg. I am too much skinny in past but with some diet and workout got some little result but not too much. anyone guide me with proper guidance about workout and diet for this worst disease.

I do a lot of workout to hide my collarbone but can not get success also.

[image: My recent image]

[image]

[image: side pose]

Comment: I don't see any problems with your physique at all. You're skinny, but that's it. You've got wide shoulders and a small waist, that's every competitive bodybuilder's dream. The only thing you need to work on is filling in your frame with more muscle.

Comment: *It could also be the angle.

Comment: I want to make chest visible so that bones outward completely hidden and no one can notice it. I want to make my chest bulky.

Comment: @JustSnilloc I have added my side pose image which clearly shows the chest defect.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how you transform yourself from 115 to 200lbs which Kind diet you eat after every 2 hours??

Comment: You don't need to eat every 2 hours, just enough calories in a day to build muscle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your feelings completely as I have a much more severe case of pectus carinatum than you. I was bullied at school and became deeply depressed for years. I was always worried about how my chest looked with clothes on and off and what a girl might say if they touched my chest. Some thought it was hard muscle, which I would feel shame about anyway as it was a lie, whilst others would point, touch, stare and ask 'what's that?' - I would die inside - It really held me back in life and contributed a lot to my depression.

I contemplated corrective surgery - there are 2 surgeries you can have - Ravitch procedure and the Reverse Nuss procedure. I met with two surgeons. Both of these surgeries are highly invasive though and I decided against it. I don't believe you need to do this.

I know this will mean nothing to you, but your physique is great. You have a VERY mild PC. As someone above said, you're blessed with a wide shoulder frame and narrow waist. I had a similar frame to you at 21 and decided to hit the gym A LOT to add bulk to mainly hide my chest. I was a typical Ectomorph (hard gainer) and 198cm tall, so I had to eat a lot and work out a lot to see any gains. I added a lot of bulk to my chest and shoulders, but it took me years. Building muscle is a long, hard process. It takes dedication and desire. It can feel sometimes, particularly when you're young and an ectomorph, that you're going nowhere. KEEP GOING. I also would always walk around like a boxer with my shoulders rounded forward to try and sink down my chest. I became big and muscular - but I was still not happy. Why?

The reason I was never happy was because I hadn't accepted myself from within. You will always live with PC, this is who you are. It's ok to be different - as hard as that is to hear, and it took me YEARS to acknowledge this fundamental to happiness. I had never learnt to love myself. I was constantly trying to chase and build a chest that I thought others would find acceptable, but I realised in my 30s that I would never achieve this as I had a warped perception of what I thought i looked like. You will only find happiness from self acceptance. And you know what? As soon as you find this, you will be happier, calmer and more confident. Girls will find you sexier because you own your shit and are comfortable in who you are.

The people who comment on your chest are almost certainly doing it from a place of self loathing about some part of their own body or something else in their lives. Anyone who accepts themselves is unlikely to want to put anyone else down. It might not be clear and obvious to you, but I guarantee this.

Go hit the gym - eat a lot of healthy protein rich food, protein shakes, creatine - build a strong, muscled body - but know that this will unlikely make you happy. Really commit to self acceptance. I cannot give you better advice than this. You will save yourself years of pain and misery. Eventually, with age, this will come, I just wish I'd given it a chance when I was your age instead of hating on myself so much.

I don't mean to minimise your experience, I really empathise with you. The pain and depression and shame is real, I'm just giving you advice having lived with the condition 13 years longer and know exactly what you're going through.

I'm now 34 and through injuries haven't been able to train as much as I used to. I'm nowhere near as muscular as I was in my 20s but I'm so much happier and at ease with my chest as a result of accepting and trying to love who I am.

WORKOUT notes. To add bulk as an ectomorph, you want to be hitting the gym at least 4 times p/w and eating a lot of clean protein rich foods. Leg days are as important as chest days. The body needs growth hormone to really build muscle and this is created through muscle stress. Your legs are your biggest muscle group so create the most growth hormone. Growth hormone circulates through the whole body so working out your legs will also help build your chest, shoulders, back and arms. You want to be obviously bench pressing heavy and full range of motion. I always found dumb bell pullovers a good outer chest builder too.

Best of luck mate.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Like Tom said your chest is not malformed and I don't know why you are calling it a disease. If one has a large chest cavity that can be attributed to large lungs and/or heart.

Your bone structure is fine and in fact well developed. Your frame is very good.

It sounds like you just want fitness advice made for someone with your particular physique. You're a sly one.

Here is a home workout.
I suggest 1 set; to absolute failure where you can't do another rep and with ultra slow-as-possible reps; of each daily:

> Walking up a hill or stairs backwards
>
> Squats with heels off ground, knees tracking over toes slightly and
> leaning forward
>
> Deep push ups with elbows flared out and hands slightly wider than
> shoulders
>
> Sit ups (all the way)
>
> Pull ups (wide or chin ups, alternating)
>
> Wrist curls with 60% of max
>
> Wrist extensions with 60% of max
>
> Wrist twists with sledgehammer at 60% of max (hold handle closer to
> head of hammer)
>
> Wrist twists with sledgehammer head on pinky side of hand at 60% of
> max
>
> Reverse push-ups with fingers pointing inward and elbows flared out;
> it'll be limited range of motion but try and get deep.
>
> Jump rope with 3" or thicker rope backwards and forwards
>
> Finger extensions (get some bands I guess)
>
> Dips leaning forward slightly and going deep.

Work up to it incorporating each exercise individually over the course of 2 months. The leg work will start up your hormonal drive and prepare you for the other stuff.

Get a BIG stretch in each rep.